# problems with var item in Model in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, azure

I make simple Azure app with ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) and SQL Server 2008 Express.
And have this mistake:
"error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WindowsAzure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

in this View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) { // error string
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TextThought)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.IdThought }, new { id = item.IdThought }) |
```

Method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View(db.GetThoughts());
    }
```

Method contents:

```
public IQueryable<Thoughts> GetThoughts()
    {
        return _db.Thoughts;
    }
```

Please Help me, Somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing or misspelt reference. Check your using statements and project references are all correct.

Comment: No, all referens are correct, becouse this code good work in ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) without Azure.
I think this error is specific Azure, but don't understand...

Comment: Based upon your error message, you are trying to use the namespace 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure' which Visual Studio is unable to resolve, hence suggesting that you check you have the correct references.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you provide us with your `using` statement?
2. Why did you need that reference? I only use explicit Azure classes for table and blob storage.
3. Are you sure you added a reference to that assembly as the error message suggests?

Comment: Could be, still can't remember

Answer (score 0):

There is very simple way you can repro this problem. Try creating a sample MVC3 ASP.NET Web Role first and then remove the the reference "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" and you will hit the exact same error where ever you will reference the methods coming out from your Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.

So the problem could that you have missing reference to "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" in your application and to solve this problem you would need to add the correct reference.

The DLL is located at as below:

C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\_SDK_Ver(v1.6)_\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll